# For the function $z = x\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} + y\sin^{-1} \frac{x}{y} + 2 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For the function

$$z = x\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} + y\sin^{-1} \frac{x}{y} + 2 $$

To find the value of  $$ x\frac {\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac {\partial z}{\partial y} $$ at (1,1)

I wanted to apply Euler's Theorem. But the 2 in function is creating problem. How do i resolve that?

Thanks

Comment: it should be a straightforward partial derivative.

Comment: I am supposed to use Euler's theorem for homogeneous fucntion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=z-2$. That is $g(x,y)=x\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} + y\sin^{-1} \frac{x}{y}$.

Then $g$ is homogeneous of order $n=1$. Therefore $xg_x+yg_y=g$.

But $g_x=z_x$ and $g_y=z_y$. Thus $$xz_x+yz_y=xg_x+yg_y=g$$.

Finally $$1z_x(1,1)+1z_y(1,1)=g(1,1)=2\tan^{-1}1=\tan^{-1}1+\sin^{-1}1=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Comment: g(1,1) = sin inverse 1  + pi\4

Comment: Yes. I thought it was $\tan^{-1}...+\tan^{-1}...$, but is $\tan^{-1}...+\sin^{-1}...$. I edited the solution